# ¿Es seguro usar nombres de dominios gratuitos?

Tags: webservice, aplicación-web, web

¿Es seguro usar nombres de dominios gratuitos ? tengo uno en de esta pagina pero la verdad no se que pensar, porque dar gratis algo no ?

https://my.freenom.com/clientarea.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un dominio, independientemente de que sea gratis o de pago, no es más que un nombre que apunta a una dirección IP. Por lo general la única diferencia entre un dominio gratuito de uno de pago es que el gratuito no te pertenece y el de pago si.

Si hablásemos de hostings gratuitos entonces si que habría que tener cuidado, ya que no sabes quien puede tener acceso al mismo y puedes llevarte una sorpresa. Pero con los dominios yo no me preocuparía demasiado.

Yo he utilizado alguna vez los dominios .tk como dominios temporales o para pruebas y nunca he tenido problemas.

Comment: muchas gracias #Enrique Carrillo siempre es bueno escuchar la voz de la experiencia.

Answer (score 2):

Generalmente tienes que asumir que nada es gratis. Si te fijaste en las condiciones de negocio, te das cuenta que tu puedes registrar todos los dominios que son gratis para un máximo de un año, para reservaciones más allá hay un listado de precios. Los precios son bastante competetívo (por ahora), pero sin embargo la pagina es poco transparente en el aspecto de los condiciónes generales de negocio.

Así si quieres un dominio para un proyecto privado no arriesgas mucho, pero si quieres armar un negocio vale la pena de pensarlo bien, porque para todos los dominios gratis vale: freenom queda dueño. Eso significa que no hay garantía sobre el precio en el futuro.